# Getting value of dropdown box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, null, dropdownbox

I'm trying to get the value of a drop down box and keep getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of null.

Heres my code:

**JS**

```
expirationYearSelectedIndex = document.getElementById("selYear").selectedIndex;
    console.log("expirationYearSelectedIndex = " + expirationYearSelectedIndex);

    expirationYear = document.getElementById("selYear").options[expirationYearSelectedIndex].value;
    console.log("expirationYear = " + expirationYear);
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
    <select id="SelYear" name="selYear">
        <option selected value=""> Select a Major....</option>
        <option value="Comptuer Information Systems"> CIS</option>
        <option value="Math"> M</option>
        <option value="CS"> CS</option>
        <option value="History"> H</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed the capital S on the ID name `<select id="SelYear" name="selYear">`

```
document.getElementById("SelYear");
```

Comment: Guess I just needed another set of eyes! Thanks so much I have looked and looked over it and thought I was coding it wrong!! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the correct answer :)

Comment: Will do! Just have to wait 6 more minutes before itll let me.